# Are Solr Collections and Cores analogous to Elasticserarch Indices and Types?

Tags: elasticsearch, solr

In Elasticsearch we have a concept of an Index that can have multiple types. This is roughly similar to the concept of databases and schemas. Now can a Solr collection be thought of as an Index/database and a Solr core be thought of as a type/schema?

**Follow up**

Does it make a difference if Solr is running in Cluster mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [core](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTerminology) in solr are analogous to the [index](https://www.elastic.co/blog/what-is-an-elasticsearch-index) in elastic search. An index is represented by core in solr, but when you get into the cloud solr (sharding, distributing documents), multiple cores can represent one logical index, which is called [collection](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTerminology) in solr. In the elastic search, it is called same `index` only.

[Mapping types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/mapping.html) are a way to divide the documents in an index into logical groups.

Comment: so when you say 'multiple cores can represent one logical index, which is called collection in solr' is that similar to the concept of shards in elasticsearch? where an index is divided into multiple shards, each shard being an independent lucene index but collectively rep[resenting one elasticsearch index?

Comment: thanks ! that makes it clear. also i was referring to mapping types in my question, not field types. looks like there is no easy way of logically segregating indices in Solr. is it possible to set the number of cores per collection in Solr? i know that in elasticsearch, we can set the number of shards.

Comment: @AbtPst you can create multiple cores in solr and manage same as creating different index in ES, each is representing one logical piece. These cores will be storing different dataset with different schema. Sharding is just distributing the documents for load balancing and other performance improvements. Let me know If I not clear to what you are asking?

Comment: @AbtPst Yes, I think solr does not allow logical grouping into a core, similar to Mapping Types in ElasticSearch.

Comment: correct, but how would i create logical separations in a Solr index? with elasticsearch, i would just create a new mapping and bind it to a new type within an index

Comment: for example, lets say i want to index some data related employees. i can see that there are different type of employees such as Managers and Associate Managers. these employees have many overlapping characteristics but i still want their search queries to be separate. Hence i will create a single index called employees, but i will also create two mappings i.e. manger and associate. can i do this with Solr?

Comment: @AbtPst I guess you need to store/index the information, whether it is employee or manager, then provide the same in your query, using the filter query (fq) parameter.

Comment: @AbtPst `Mapping Type` is deprecated in new version(6.0.0) of ElasticSearch!